# Scala method with generic return type

Tags: scala, generics

I have a function which consists of parsing a json file to return a json defined configuration type:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson

def parseJsonFile(pathToFile: String): JsonConfig = {

  var configuration = null
  val gson: Gson = new Gson
  val jsonAsString: String = sparkContext
      .textFile(pathToFile)
      .collect
      .mkString

  configuration = gson.fromJson(jsonAsString, classOf[JsonConfig])
  configuration

}

class JsonConfig {

  var tableName: String = _
  var hiveSchema: String = _

}
```

Is it possible to construct a single method that returns a generic type `A` like for example:

```
def parseJsonFile[A](pathToFile: String): A = {

  var configuration = null
  val gson: Gson = new Gson
  val jsonAsString: String = sparkContext
      .textFile(pathToFile)
      .collect
      .mkString

  configuration = gson.fromJson(jsonAsString, classOf[A])
  configuration

}
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, use a `ClassTag` and don't use *null*:

```
import scala.reflect.{ClassTag, classTag}

def parseJsonFile[A: ClassTag](pathToFile: String): A = {
  val gson: Gson = new Gson
  val jsonAsString: String = sparkContext
      .textFile(pathToFile)
      .collect
      .mkString

  val aClass = classTag[A].runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[A]]
  gson.fromJson(jsonAsString, aClass)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.
When I tried it, I have the following error :
```Type mismatch. Required : A. Found: Null```.
The function does not return the correct type.

Comment: @Mamaf Change the metod signature to `def parseJsonFile[A >: Null : ClassTag](pathToFile: String): A` or even `def parseJsonFile[A >: Null <: AnyRef : ClassTag](pathToFile: String): A`. Not all types can be initialized with `null`. Do you really need that `var`? https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/yIbkRfAdRsmXlgfEXJIiCg/1 With `val` you don't need `>: Null`.

Comment: @DmytroMitin Thank you but I still have this error : ```ERROR: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to invoke public scala.runtime.Nothing$() with no args``` when I used the ```fromJson``` method.

Comment: @Mamaf Well, you not **still** have error. You had compile error, now you have runtime exception.

Comment: @Mamaf How do you call `parseJsonFile`? Do you provide `A` in `parseJsonFile[A]("...")`?